# read file in form with js codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i need to create a form with two textarea and 1 file input that uploads a txt/csv file where there are 2 numbers in two row (1 row - 1 number) and popolate the 2 textarea with the two numbers using codeigniter and Javascript. thanks for the help

```
file:

     59.8
     42.8
     55.8
     51.1
```

html

```
<input type="file" id="id">
<br>
<textarea id="result1" cols="50"></textarea>
<textarea id="result2" cols="50"></textarea>
<textarea id="result3" cols="50"></textarea>
<textarea id="result4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

this is the js if there is 1 textarea where print the result but every row need to be print in a single textarea and doens't work

```js
  $("#id").on('change', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
      
        var result = document.getElementById("param3");
      
        reader.onload = function(event) {
          result.innerHTML = event.target.result;
        };
      
        reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
    });
```

Comment: <input type="file" id="id">

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use `split()` to convert the value read from the text file in to an array, with one element per line of text.

Then you can loop through that array and set the values within each `textarea`. Try this:

```html
<input type="file" id="id"><br />

<textarea class="result" id="result1" cols="50"></textarea>
<textarea class="result" id="result2" cols="50"></textarea>
<textarea class="result" id="result3" cols="50"></textarea>
<textarea class="result" id="result4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

```js
let $results = $('.result');

$("#id").on('change', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = e => {
    e.target.result.split(/\r\n/).forEach((text, i) => {
      $results.eq(i).val(text);
    });
  };
  reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
});
```

Note that I applied the same `class` attribute to the textarea elements to make the logic much simpler. Generally speaking, incremental `id` attributes are an anti-pattern and should be avoided where possible.

Here's a working example in a [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/eo9jswz7/) (as SO snippets are sandboxed and cannot use `FileReader`). You'll need to create a text file yourself to see it in action.